# Render image src with URL variable and send as an email

Tags: html, image, email, symfony, twig

I want to do something like this inside a Twig template:

```
<img src="{{ img_path }}/logo.jpg" />
```

and send it with a `mailer` function (not `mailto`).

The `{{ img_path }}` is correct, because if I add:

```
<p>{{ img_path }}</p>
```

It is shown correctly (`http://siteURL/img`). And if I add `/logo.jpg` and put it on the URL, I'm getting the image.

But in the email, the image `src` attribute is a Google URL (I'm using Gmail to send) and the desired URL after that (`https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/somecharacters#http://siteURL/img/logo.jpg`), so the image is not showing.

Any idea of what is happening here and how to solve it?

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm working on my localhost. This could be the problem.

Comment: You might be using a relative path. Instead, try setting {{ img_path }} to the absolute URL.

Comment: @dward - It's not a relative path, but it's maybe because I'm working on localhost, and Google can't access it, because I've seen more images with a similar URL in some emails.

Comment: Maybe try installing a local mail catcher, like smtp4dev, and see if you can capture the mail locally and see it works correctly (or with different results). You'd think that if the URL is absolute, then it would show as "localhost". Also, you might check your open/closing tags as well as any concatenation strings you have in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently (December 2013) Gmail started [caching all images](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html). It was a trade off as now images load by default, but they are hosted by Google's Proxy server, not your original URL.

Sounds like this caching is applying to your outbound email also.